# Angular 2 how can i make my variable wait async for values?

Tags: angular

I have this error :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at PaginationComponent.ngOnChanges (pagination.component.ts:38)

This is my `PaginationComponent`:

```
@Input() items = [];
@Input('page-size') pageSize;
@Output('page-changed') pageChanged = new EventEmitter();
pages: any[];
currentPage; 
public numberofpages = 10;
ngOnChanges(){
    this.currentPage = 1;
    var pagesCount = this.items.length / this.pageSize; 
    this.pages = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= pagesCount; i++)
        this.pages.push(i);
}
```

This how I am using it in another component `AboutUsComponent`:

```
<pagination [items]="posts" [page-size]="pageSize" (page-changed)="onPageChanged($event)"></pagination>
```

And the posts are loaded in AboutUsComponent:

```
private loadPosts(){
    this.postsLoading = true;
    this._aboutusService.getPosts().subscribe( 
        posts => {this.posts = posts;
                  this.pagedPosts = this.getPostsInPage(1)}, 
        null, 
        () => { this.postsLoading = false});
}
```

As I understand it happens because of `.subscribe()` async loading of posts and `@Input() items = [];` could be loaded before posts come.
How can I make it await or what over solution may you suggest?
Thank you.

Comment: You are loading `this.posts` but you use `this.items.length`. Perhaps you need to change it to `this.posts.length`

Comment: Why do you use OnChanges ? Try OnInit. Also, when does your component trigger loadPosts ?

Comment: `ngOnChange` fires ones at the beginning of the life cycle of the component. Use `try/catch` or put `if` condition to bypass this error. Also i think better approach is to use specific events when you want to rearrange your items.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the parameter of the `ngChanges` method to be sure that the changes correspond to `items`. This way, you would be sure that the `items` input is set:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
  if (changes['items']) { // <----
    this.currentPage = 1;
    var pagesCount = this.items.length / this.pageSize; 
    this.pages = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= pagesCount; i++)
      this.pages.push(i);
    }
  }
}
```

The `ngOnChanges` method is called for every change even on the `pageSize` input...

Comment: SimpleChanges is underlined and the error message is "Cannot find name 'SimpleChanges'" ?

Comment: Do you import it from the `@angular/core` module? `import { SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';`

Comment: After importing SimpleChanges the underline on SimpleChanges  disappear, but now there is another one  on changes.items in if statement  "Property 'items' does not exist on type 'SimpleChanges'."

Comment: Yes, you're right! You should change `changes.items` to `changes['items']` because of the declaration of the SimpleChanges interface: `export interface SimpleChanges { [propName: string]: SimpleChange; }`.

Comment: anyway the same error Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: What is the content of the `changes` object when `ngOnChanges` is called? Thanks!

Comment: I have uploaded here https://cloud.mail.ru/public/GmR9/q6F3pEdHa the pagination component and about component where I am using this pagination, don't know why I'm not able to import code here.